# Custom UIButton's setIsSelected method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a custom class based on UIButton, and I have difficulties calling the custom setter method in this custom class. I will list the codes in these files:

1. CallMyMethod.h (subclass of UIButton)
2. CallMyMethod.m
3. CallOtherClassMethod.h (to call setter method in CallMyMethod)
4. CallOtherClassMethod.m

**CallMyMethod.h**

```
@interface CallMyMethod : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, setter=setIsSelected:) BOOL isSelected;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *checkmarkImageView;

- (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)aIsSelected; //this is unnecessary, I guess

@end
```

**CallMyMethod.m**

```
@implementation CallMyMethod

@synthesize isSelected = _isSelected;
@synthesize checkmarkImageView = _checkmarkImageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self loadView];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) loadView
{
  [self.checkmarkImageView setHidden:YES];
}

- (UIImageView *)checkmarkImageView
{
    if (_checkmarkImageView == nil) {

      UIImage *checkmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"];

      _checkmarkImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:checkmarkImage];

      [_checkmarkImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 32, 32)];

      [self addSubview:_checkmarkImageView];
  }

  return _checkmarkImageView;
}

- (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)aIsSelected
{
  _isSelected = aIsSelected;

  [self.checkmarkImageView setHidden:!_isSelected];
  [self addSubview:_checkmarkImageView];

}

@end
```

**CallOtherClassMethod.h**

```
@class CallMyMethod;    

@interface CallOtherClassMethod : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) CallMyMethod *btnCMM;

@end
```

**CallOtherClassMethod.m**

```
#import "CallMyMethod.h"

@implementation CallOtherClassMethod

@synthesize btnCMM;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.btnCMM = [[CallMyMethod alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 50, 70)];

  //somewhere in my code I will add btnCMM to the view
  [someView bringSubviewToFront: btnCMM];
  [someView addSubview: btnCMM];

}

//somewhere where I pressed a button to trigger this method
- (IBAction) pressMe:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"self.btnCMM %@", self.btnCMM); //returned as btnCMM is nil ?!
  [self.btnCMM setIsSelected:YES];
}

@end
```

The issue lies in the program not able to run the codes in setIsSelected method, I have traced btnCMM to be nil in NSLog. I wonder why is this so, because when I call CallOtherClassMethod as a UIViewController, the viewDidLoad would have initialised my custom button. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you adding btnCMM to a view somewhere? You create it in viewDidLoad, but you never add it as a subview. In what method does the log say btnCMM is nil?

Comment: Yes, I have added btnCMM to a view somewhere. thanks for reminding me this, I will add that to the code. I was doing an abstract for this question and missed out these details.

will be adding the NSLog as well, its inside the pressMe method

Answer (score 0):

Why not override setSelected, which is a method on UIButton and then use `button.selected = YES`?

If you want to debug why your button becomes nil, implement dealloc in your UIButton subclass, put a breakpoint there, and see the stack trace to find the reason.

Comment: i tried using selected in UIButton which comes with it, but it does not work too.

Comment: @xiaodouya try putting a break point in dealloc as ive written in the answer

Comment: i am trying that now but getting weird response from the app.

i put this - (void) dealloc
    {
    
    } as a method in CallMyMethod.m (UIButton subclass) and breakpoint at the first line of method. The app crashes on the second time it is called in CallOtherClassMethod. App crashes in iOS 7.1 but doesn't crash in iOS 8.3

Comment: @xiaodouya what's the stack trace for the crash?

Comment: sorry, i said wrongly, it was a breakpoint, not a crash. app is working fine. Back to the point of putting a breakpoint and dealloc method, how do I find the reason why my button is nil?

Comment: it says "start of stack trace" Thread 1: [btnCMM dealloc], [UIView release] "dotted line" objc_storeStrong, [CallOtherClassMethod .cxx_destruct], object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) "dotted line" UIApplicationMain, main, start  "end"

anything to look out for?

Comment: @xiaodouya this suggests your view controller is being deallocated

Comment: are you saying CallMyOtherClassMethod view controller is getting deallocated which explains why btnCMM is nil?

Comment: @xiaodouya seems so, yes.

Comment: thanks for helping me this far, rounak, it seems like the code to initialize btnCMM in viewDidLoad of CallOtherClassMethod was done but the app goes immediately to dealloc which made the btnCMM nil. However, I can still see the labels initialized and added to someView (visually appeared) in CallOtherClassMethod's viewDidLoad, why is this so?